# Print first element or 2nd element from text file

Tags: python

Simple text file:

```
whatevera, what2
whateverb, what3
whateverc, what4
whateverd, what5
```

or

```
(whatevera, what2)
(whateverb, what3)
(whateverc, what4)
(whateverd, what5)
```

Prints it line by line.

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print line
```

What's best way to print just first element or second element by looping
through each line using forloop?

```
    for line in f:
        print line[0]
whatevera
whateverb
whateverc
whateverd
```

2nd element

```
    for line in f:
        print line[1]

what2
what3
what4
what5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function to get the columns:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    first, second = zip(*[line.rstrip().split(',') for line in fp])
    print first
    print second
```

Since this approach will print the items in a `tuple` if you want to print the items in a column mode you can join the words with a new-line character:

```
print '\n'.join(first)
```

If you want to access to lines before print (modify them or etc.) you can simple loop and split. You better to loop over the `frist` and `second` `tuples` from aforementioned script. Otherwise it's not an optimized and pythonic way to separately loop over the file for accessing the first and second items.

Comment: @user5977290 You need to split the lines with `,` then apply the `zip` function. Try it now.

Comment: What's way to print just the first list by looping?  for example, this prints the first element  ->  for line in first, second:
     print line[0]

Comment: I think he wants them separately.  That is, print all of the first elements, then print all the second elements.

Comment: @user5977290: If you don't want to print the second elements at all, just take out the `print second` line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the function `split()` in python.  Using a function will allow you to reuse the code.

```
def create_list(filename):
    element_list = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line_data = line.split(',') 
'''you can change line_data[0] to line_data[1]
if you want to print the next half of the txt line'''
            element_list.append(line_data[0])  
return element_list

print(create_list('file.txt'))
```

You can later append the line_data[1] to a different list if you want.